# What HTTP Status Code to return from REST API if user has not upload required files before calling confirm endpoint?

Tags: rest, httpresponse, http-status-codes

If user has to upload files and confirm them via API endpoint call, what status code should be returned if user calls the confirm endpoint but has not uploaded all of the required files?

`400` doesn't seem to be right because there is nothing wrong with the request parameters.
`403` doesn't seem to be right because there is nothing wrong with credentials.

Comment: Why are files not uploaded?

Comment: User has to manually upload the files and then confirm them with a separate API request.

Comment: What does confirmation endpoint look like?

Comment: Could be something like `POST` `/order/<orderId>/files/confirm`

Comment: Perhaps, I would consider 409 or 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The *403 (Forbidden)* status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to fulfill it.... a request might be forbidden for reasons unrelated to the credentials. -- [HTTP Semantics](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.5.4)

Keep in mind that status codes are metadata in the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s) domain; they tell HTTP components how to interpret the fields and body in the HTTP response.

See also Mark Nottingham on the [generic semantics of status codes](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2017/05/11/status_codes#generic-semantics).

---

I don't think it is as good a choice, but it [409 conflict](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.5.10) is an alternative that is probably harmless?

> The *409 (Conflict)* status code indicates that the request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request. -- [HTTP Semantics](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.5.10)